# Batch File Unable To Compare Two String Variables

Tags: batch-file, robocopy, xcopy

The company I work at utilizes a batch file to backup user profiles. The script originally used robocopy, but now also uses xcopy in some cases. We run this script manually when re-imaging users to copy all of their files/folders, as well as some customizations, to their personal network drive. We then can access this information on their new laptop and run the script again to re-apply everything to their new machine.

We noticed over hundreds of uses that occasionally this script would just not backup either the user's Desktop or Documents files and/or folders. We cannot find a consistent variable that causes this hiccup in our script though, and I have been tasked with updating the batch script so that we can eliminate this issue.

My thought was to include a check of sorts into the program to ensure that everything was copied over, and if not to run the backup of that specific destination again. To do this I run the following lines to grab an image of the file size of that folder, and all of it's sub-folders:

```bash
set backupdesktopsize=.set secondline=.

@FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=^^" %%G IN ('dir "%BackupDestination%\Desktop" /s /a') DO (set backupdesktopsize=!secondline!set secondline=%%G)
```

I am then able to `echo !backupdesktopsize!` and get:

```
x Files(s) xxx,xxx bytes
```

So I run this script for both the original Desktop location found on the local drive of the machine, and then I run it again for the backup destination on the personal network drive. I can then echo each individual variable and confirm that they are both returning the data I am looking for. I am also able to check the properties of the folders themselves and confirm that what my program is running is gathering the correct data.

The issue then comes in when I attempt to run a boolean to compare the two variables that I have created. As it stands my code for this is currently:

```bash
if "!desktopsize!" == "!backupdesktopsize!" (echo The backup of the Desktop file(s) and folder(s) was a success!) else (echo The backup of the Desktop file(s) and folder(s) did not match. RoboCopy will run the Desktop back up again.)
```

When the program gets to this point it crashes without error every time.

I know that my problem is within the boolean itself, but I am unable to understand what I am missing. I found another post here where a user had a similar issue and found out it was the white space in the string that was causing issues when comparing. So, I then used the code he implemented to remove the white space from the strings I had with this:

```bash
set backupdesktopsize=%backupdesktopsize: =%
```

And this does work to change what was previously echoed to be the following instead.

```
xFiles(s)xxx,xxxbytes
```

Still, when attempting to run the boolean the program continues to crash. I have played around with changing the syntax of the boolean a lot, and looked around online, but cannot figure out what I am missing. I would really appreciate it if anyone would be able to offer some solutions, or alternatives for how I can build some redundancy into this script.

Comment: I would assume that each of your nested and `echo`ed closing parentheses will need to be escaped with carets! ```if "!desktopsize!" == "!backupdesktopsize!" (echo The backup of the Desktop file(s^) and folder(s^) was a success!) else (echo The backup of the Desktop file(s^) and folder(s^) did not match. RoboCopy will run the Desktop back up again.)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is tempting to condense the script, and have the `echo` on a single line, this is Windows batch -- the usual guidelines for style & good taste do not apply.

You should **not** have this nested if/else `echo` on a single line.

This is better:

```bash
if     "!desktopsize!" == "!backupdesktopsize!" echo The backup of the Desktop file(s) and folder(s) was a success!
if not "!desktopsize!" == "!backupdesktopsize!" echo The backup of the Desktop file(s) and folder(s) did not match. RoboCopy will run the Desktop back up again.
```

When taking multiple actions, use appropriate `goto`s:

```bash
if "!desktopsize!" == "!backupdesktopsize!" goto success
REM -- Otherwise, not the same, skip down to the error condition
goto error

:error
echo The backup of the Desktop file(s) and folder(s) did not match. RoboCopy will run the Desktop back up again.
REM -- Take action here, or go back and repeat from a previous label
goto end

:success
echo The backup of the Desktop file(s) and folder(s) was a success!
REM -- Good to go!
goto end

:end
```